# Why is this custom volume animation slider not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, math

I created a custom volume animation slider but it isn't working properly. I'm actually having trouble figuring out what's happening - the volume and slider are changing, but not as expected. Here's the code:

```js
$(function() {
  var $volumeBar = $('#Volume-Bar');
  var $volumeContainer = $('#Volume-Container');
  var $value = $('.value');
  
  $volumeContainer.on('mousedown', function(event) {
    var height = $volumeContainer.height();
    var startingCoord = event.offsetY;
    var currentCoord;
    var percent;
    var difference;
    seekingVol = true;
    $volumeContainer.on('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
      if (seekingVol) {
        seekingVol = false;
      }
    });
    $volumeContainer.on('mousemove', function(event) {
      if (seekingVol) {
        currentCoord = event.offsetY;
        percent = (currentCoord / height) * 100;
        $value.html(percent + '%');
        $volumeBar.css({
          'height': percent + '%'
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter:700);

.value {
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
  position:absolute;
  color:white;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  font-family:Bitter;
  font-size:20px;
  pointer-events:none;
}
#Volume-Container {
  position:relative;
  width:75px;
  height:150px;
  background-color:#0e2030;
  display: -webkit-box;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
 -webkit-box-direction:normal;
 -webkit-flex-direction:column;
     -ms-flex-direction:column;
         flex-direction:column;
 -webkit-box-align: center;
 -webkit-align-items: center; 
     -ms-flex-align: center;
         align-items: center;
 -webkit-box-pack: center;
 -webkit-justify-content: center;
     -ms-flex-pack: center;
         justify-content: center;
}
#Volume-Bar {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  height:30%;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#6ab2f2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Volume-Container">
  <div class="value">0%</div>
  <div id="Volume-Bar"></div>
</div>
```

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple errors.

- You're using the FlexBox model which is very new, poorly supported and often buggy. Just to put one DIV inside another anchored at the bottom, this is such a level of overkill it isn't even funny. You can centre your volume text by putting it in a DIV that matches the outermost container height (150px) and setting `line-height` to `150px` too. Your CSS could and should be much, *much* simpler.
- You're using OffsetY which Mozilla's documentation via Google describes as 'experimental'. In Safari, this seems to not work properly at all so on that browser you'll never get a working slider. You need to use a different API.
- You've apparently not realised that coordinates start with 0 at the *top* of the page or containers and increasing downwards, so when you're calculating the percentage, it gets *lower* as the mouse pointer is closer to the top of the box instead of higher. This is a very common arrangement for coordinate handling in GUIs - (0,0) is top left, increasing positive to the right and downwards.
- You're not rounding the calculation to an integer for display.
- You're using jQuery animations but not cancelling any prior animation so they just stack up one after the other and jQuery will just run them in sequence until they all finish.
- Your HTML puts the volume percentage text behind the blue slider so the slider hides the text.

Addressing some of these:

```
$(function() {
  var $volumeBar = $('#Volume-Bar');
  var $volumeContainer = $('#Volume-Container');
  var $value = $('.value');

  $volumeContainer.on('mousedown', function(event) {
    var height = $volumeContainer.height();
    var top = $volumeContainer.position().top;
    var startingCoord = event.clientY - top;
    var currentCoord;
    var percent;
    var difference;
    seekingVol = true;
    $volumeContainer.on('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
      if (seekingVol) {
        seekingVol = false;
      }
    });
    $volumeContainer.on('mousemove', function(event) {
      if (seekingVol) {
        currentCoord = event.clientY - top;
        percent = ((height - currentCoord) / height) * 100;
        $value.html(Math.round(percent) + '%');
        $volumeBar.finish();
        $volumeBar.animate({
          'height': percent + '%'
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

This:

1. Reads the `top` of the volume container.
2. Works out the starting coordinate based on the not-experimental `clientY` property, which is a page-wide coordinate with the top of the page (scrolled or otherwise) at zero, subtracting the top of the volume container from the result to get an offset within that volume container. I don't account for margin or padding here. You *could* do that in the script, but it'd be much easier to adjust your HTML - e.g. adding in an outer wrapper DIV - so that the `#Volume-Container` DIV has no margins or padding.
3. Uses `Math.round` for display.
4. Calculates the percentage as `((height - currentCoord) / height) * 100` so now, at the top of the bar, you get 100% instead of 0%.
5. Calls jQuery `.finish` to cancel prior animations. In practice given your code structure and event usage, this really means that there's basically no animation on the volume slider at all. Personally, I'd ditch that animation completely and just set the height; it's much more responsive that way and looks much nicer than some weird floating laggy catchup game that you'd get otherwise (and will actually be quite hard to code for given the way the jQuery animation interface appears to work, from a quick read of their API docs).

Your percentage text fixes by just swapping the HTML ordering:

```
<div id="Volume-Container">
  <div id="Volume-Bar"></div>
  <div class="value">0%</div>
</div>
```

...but you've no doubt already found out that now, dragging the mouse over the volume slider sometimes selects the text. Fixing this is an exercise for the reader; personally, I'd probably give up and put the text underneath the volume slider where it's not going to have to be legible over different background colours as the slider moves.

Comment: Of your first bullets, while valid, I'd point out that #1, 4, & 6 dont seem relevant to the weird performance (Those were incidental errors due to creating a quick simple example demonstrating the real problem - the JS).

Comment: @Viziionary You simply said, "but it isn't working properly" and "What's wrong with this?". You didn't ask about the weird performance (the drifting is caused by stacking the animations).

There was a _lot_ wrong with it and I stand by the comprehensive answer. Don't take it personally; we only grow as coders by accepting that sometimes we make mistakes :-) - there will be better ways than the solutions I present I'm sure, but it's an iterative thing and eventually you reach the point of "good enough".

Comment: Also your last paragraph, I assume, was written without realizing my final edits to the question - I added CSS rules to avoid he text selection. Again, just an incidental aspect of my example.

Comment: (Shrug) I guess next time maybe I won't bother helping. (Edit): Noting that relatively new CSS stuff like user-select won't work on e.g. Opera Mini, but you might not care because it's a minority browser. http://caniuse.com/#feat=user-select-none

Comment: I see. Incidentally, a question like mine here is technically on topic on SO, but its such a specific question i doubt it would ever help anyone else. Im surprised SO doesnt focus more on accepting fundamental questions rather than on helping each user individually with questions like mine. Do you have any thoughts on this, personally?

Comment: I think you misinterpreted the intention of my comment. I'm grateful for your help. I'd upvote but I lack the rep.

Comment: That's a good question. As I see it, someone else might have issues with a JS slider which could be due e.g. CSS issues, the coordinate system's directionality or animation within jQuery. Your specific issue is indeed very bespoke, and while we all want to avoid Stack Overflow being somewhere that colloquially "does your homework for you", if answers are reasonably comprehensive there's a good chance of a Google hit leading to a solution for someone with a related issue. So it's about contributing to a wider body of knowledge / bearing in mind internet archives.

Comment: Also, apologies if I misinterpreted your the intent of your responses. They seemed very defensive but I was probably just being grumpy ;) and in the wider sense your question was well-formed because it included a complete working example that could be modified via JSFiddle. Without that, I wouldn't have attempted to help - too much time wasted to setting things up.